# (MySQL) Ignore lines with a starting symbol when importing a file

Tags: mysql, input

I have an input file I want to load into a MySQL database, but spread throughout the file are comment lines, which start with `!`. For example,

```
!dataset_value_type = count
```

The other lines that I want to read into the table are normal, without the leading `!`.

What is the import command to ignore lines that start with `!`? I just see commands to ONLY take lines that start with something (`LINES STARTING BY`)

Comment: How are you importing this? Are you using a query to import it?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch!  I think you will need to pre-process your data file.  Something like:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/^!.*$//;'  data-file.dat
```